# Installing Virtual Box problem

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and tried to install Virtual Box on my system. I downloaded setup for 16.04 directly from Oracle site, ran through Ubuntu Software of course, and I suspected already when it didn't start install on one click, I needed to click twice, then I got install icon on my dock, which didn't load for about 10 minutes. I restarted, then I got error message on picture.

- Question 1: How to fix that error?
- Question 2: How do I get clear install of Virtual Box?

[image: Apt error message]

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: Once you reverted your earlier mistake see [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](/q/41478/175814)

Answer (score 0):

The line 52 of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is wrong.

My guess being the `deb` prefix is missing.

Look at how the other (uncommented) lines are formatted.

Note: VirtualBox should be available using Ubuntu official repositories. You shouldn't need to install Oracle repository.